# Ruby on Rails - How do I split string and Number?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string `"FooFoo2014"`.

I want the result to be => `"Foo Foo 2014"`

Any idea?

Comment: Is input always fixed ? Never FooBaaz2014 ? or something like that ?

Comment: What makes "FooFoo" become "Foo Foo" ?  Is it capital letters?  Split in half?  Every third letter is a new word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"FooFoo2014"
.gsub(/(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/, " ")
# => "Foo Foo 2014"
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

```
puts "FooFoo2014".scan(/(\d+|[A-Z][a-z]+)/).join(' ')
# => Foo Foo 2014
```

Of course in condition that you separate numbers and words from capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a little generic. So this might be guessing in the wrong direction. That being said, it seems like you want to reformat the string a little:

```
 "FooFoo2014".scan(/^([A-Z].*)([A-Z].*\D*)(\d+)$/).flatten.join(" ")
```

As `"FooFoo2014"` is a string with some internal structure important to you, you need to come up with the right regular expression yourself.

From your question, I extract two tasks:

1. split the FooFoo at the capital letter.

   `/([A-Z].*)([A-Z].*)/` would do that, given you only have standard latin letters
2. split the letter from the digits

   `/(.*\D)(\d+)/` achieves that.

The result of scan is an array in my version of ruby. Please verify that in your setup.

If you think that regular expressions are too complicated for this, I suggest that you take a good look into ActiveSupport. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.1/ might help you.

Answer (score -1):

If its only letters then only digits:

```
target = "FooFoo2014"
match_data = target.match(/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/)
p match_data[1] # => "FooFoo"
p match_data[2] # => "2014
```

If it is two words each made of one capitalized letter then lowercase letters, then digits:

```
target = "FooBar2014"
match_data = target.match(/([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)(\d+)/)

p match_data[1] # => "Foo"
p match_data[2] # => "Bar"
p match_data[3] # => "2014
```

Better regex are probably possible.